# Which form of this quadratic do i use to solve intercept and range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

So my equation is:
$-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = 0$

If I use this form to look at my y intercept, it will be 30.
However, once I simplify it to: $x^2 - 2x - 15$, then my y intercept will be $-15$. Which one do I use? Inclusively, I was taught that if the quadratic is positive, it is in a U shape, and if it is negative, it is an upside-down U shape.

How do I know which form to use to solve these questions?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not $-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = 0$, but $f(x)=-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = -2(x^2-2x-15)$. You must find the $y$ intercept of a **function**, rather than an **equation**. To find the $y$ intercept, you need to let $x=0.$

$$f(0)=-2(0^2-2(0)-15)=-2(0-0-15)=-2(-15)=30$$

Thus, the $y$ intercept still occurs at $(0,30)$

When $-2x^2 + 4x + 30 = 0$, you are saying that you are trying to find where $f(x)=0$, and not a general function, $f(x)$. Note that $f(x)=-2x^2 + 4x + 30 \neq x^2-2x-15 $

Please comment if what I have said does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are interested in finding the range indicates that you were originally given the *quadratic function* 
$$f(x) = -2x^2 + 4x + 30$$ 
to graph.  Its graph is the set of points $(x, y)$ in the Cartesian plane that satisfy the equation $y = -2x^2 + 4x + 30$.

**Domain:**  The domain of any polynomial function is the set of all real numbers.  Hence, the domain of $f(x) = -2x^2 + 4x + 30$ is 
$$D_f = \mathbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$$

**Range:**  We complete the square to transform the equation from the standard form 
$$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$ 
to the vertex form 
$$f(x) = a(x - h)^2 + k$$ 
where $(h, k)$ is the vertex of the graph of the parabola $y = ax^2 + bx + c$.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = -2x^2 + 4x + 30\\
     & = -2(x^2 - 2x) + 30\\
     & = -2\left[x^2 - 2x + \left(-\frac{2}{2}\right)^2\right] + 2\left(-\frac{2}{2}\right)^2 + 30\\
     & = -2(x^2 - 2x + 1) + 2 + 30\\
     & = -2(x - 1)^2 + 32
\end{align*}
Hence, the graph of $f(x)$ has vertex $(1, 32)$.  Since $(x - 1)^2 \geq 0$ for any real number $x$, 
$$-2(x - 1)^2 \leq 0 \implies -2(x - 1)^2 + 32 \leq 32$$
Thus, the function $f(x)$ has maximum value $32$, which is achieved when $x = 1$.  Since $f(x) \leq 32$, the graph of the parabola opens downwards.  Since $-2(x - 1)^2 + 32 \to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$, the range of $f(x)$ is 
$$R_f = (-\infty, 32] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \leq -32\}$$ 
The graph opens downwards since the coefficient of $x^2$ is negative.

If you are not comfortable with completing the square, you can use the formula 
$$x = -\frac{b}{2a}$$
to find the equation of the axis of symmetry (the vertical line through the vertex of the parabola), then substitute that value of $x$ into the function to find the $y$-coordinate of the vertex.

> **Note:**  When the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive in the equation $$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = a(x - h)^2 + k$$  the graph opens upwards and
>   has a minimum value of $k$ when $x = h$.  On the graph, the minimum value occurs at the vertex $(h, k)$.  The range of the function is $[k, \infty)$.
>
> When the coefficient of $x^2$ is negative in the equation
>   $$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = a(x - h)^2 + k$$ 
>   the graph opens downwards and has a maximum value of $k$ at $x = h$.  On the graph, the maximum value occurs at the vertex $(h, k)$.  The range of the function is $(-\infty, k]$.

**$\boldsymbol{x}$-intercepts:**  The $x$-intercepts occur where the graph intersects the $x$-axis, which is the line $y = 0$.  To find the $x$-intercepts, we set $f(x) = 0$ and solve for $x$.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 0\\
-2x^2 + 4x + 30 & = 0 && \text{substitute $-2x^2 + 4x + 30$ for $f(x)$}\\
x^2 - 2x - 15 & = 0 && \text{divide each side of the equation by $2$}\\
(x - 5)(x + 3) & = 0 && \text{factor the resulting quadratic}
\end{align*}
Setting each factor equal to zero yields
\begin{align*}
x - 5 & = 0 & x + 3 & = 0\\
x & = 5 & x & = -3
\end{align*}
which correspond to the points $(5, 0)$ and $(-3, 0)$ on the graph of the parabola $y = -2x^2 + 4x + 30$.

Alternatively, set $-2(x - 1)^2 + 32 = 0$ and solve for $x$.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 0\\
-2(x - 1)^2 + 32 & = 0 && \text{substitute $-2(x - 1)^2 + 32$ for $f(x)$}\\
(x - 1)^2 - 16 & = 0 && \text{divide each side of the equation by $-2$}\\
(x - 1)^2 & = 16 && \text{add $16$ to each side of the equation}\\
|x - 1| & = 4 && \text{take square roots}
\end{align*}
Since $|x - 1| = 4$ means the number $x - 1$ is $4$ units from zero, either $x - 1 = 4$ or $x - 1 = -4$.
\begin{align*}
x - 1 & = 4 & x - 1 & = -4\\
x & = 5 & x & = -3
\end{align*}

**$\boldsymbol{y}$-intercept:**  The $y$-intercept occurs where the graph of the function intersects the $y$-axis, which is the line $x = 0$.  To solve for the $y$-intercept, evaluate $f(x)$ when $x = 0$.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = -2x^2 + 4x + 30\\
f(0) & = -2 \cdot 0^2 + 4 \cdot 0 + 30 && \text{substitute $0$ for $x$}\\
     & = -2 \cdot 0 + 0 + 30\\
     & = 0 + 0 + 30\\
     & = 30
\end{align*}
On the graph of the parabola $y = -2x^2 + 4x + 30$, the $y$-intercept is the point $(0, 30)$.

Answer (score -1):

It does not simplify to $x^{2} - 2x - 15$, you have to continue to account for the $-2$ you factored out:

$$-2x^{2} + 4x + 30 = -2(x^{2} - 2x - 15) = 0 $$

Evaluating at $x = 0$, the intercept remains $(0,30)$.

Comment: I divided everything by -2, and when you do that you get x^2−2x−15

Comment: Yes, but the $-2$ doesn't go away. If so, you're describing two different quadratics, which is why you have the apparent discrepancy. What you're claiming is equivalent to dividing $4$ by $2$ and writing $4 = 2$.

Comment: I see now. However, why is the intercept 30 and not -15, as factored above?

Comment: The intercept here is describing the point where the quadratic crosses the $y$-axis. This occurs when $x=0$, by definition. So just plug in: in the first one, $-2\cdot 0^{2} + 4\cdot 0 + 30 = 0 + 0 + 30 = 30$ and in the second one, $-2(0^{2} - 2\cdot 0 - 15) = -2(-15) = 30$

Comment: To recap, when I look to see whether the graph is U or upside-down U, I always need to factor everything out, then look at what remains?

Comment: For the direction of the curve, you need only look at the $ax^{2}$ term. If $a > 0$, then it points upward. If $a < 0$, it points downward. No factoring is necessary here.

Comment: a is less than 0, but the graph is still pointing upwards when factored

Comment: Just to make sure we're clear--"pointing upwards" means "U" shaped and downwards is the "upside-down" U. For more clarity, "pointing upwards" can be generally called _convex_ and downwards is _concave_. Also be careful: Factoring does not change the essence of the quadratic. Much like $12 = 3\times 2\times 2$--both quantities are $12$. Same here with the quadratic. The factored and unfactored forms are equivalent.

Comment: In the factored form, a is > 0. In the original form, a is < 0. Which one do I use?

Comment: $a$ is not greater than zero. Do not refer to the factored form for the direction. Factoring the $-2$ "absorbs" the $-2$ from $-2x^{2}$, but $a$ is still $-2$. You're not changing anything by factoring.

Comment: I see why I'm having this confusion. I thought that the correct answer would be that the graph is pointing up. So when I solve things such as y intercept, vertex and range, there is no need for factoring, except when it comes to SOLVING by factoring, correct?

Comment: In general, you can see the $y$-intercept, vertex, and range without solving. So, yes, I would say factoring greatest use in this type of question is for solving the quadratic for its roots.